# httpcontext.current.request default return value if not set

Tags: httpcontext, request.querystring

I've spent a lot of time googling this and testing in my program, but I can't get any output. I'm coding in C# codebehind aspx. I'm trying to query the url of

anUnknownWebsite.aspx?SerialNumber=CND0340482

And getting the serial number with the httpcontext.current.request["SerialNumber"] method.

One half of my program works fine, where if the serial number is set in the URL, everything works fine, but I want to have a boolean statement like the following:

```
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request["SerialNumber"] == null)
    {
    Do this
    }else
    {
    Do something else
    }
```

I just want to know if the method will have a default value or a null value to get a boolean from because the if statement above doesn't work.
Open to try any new ideas or theories on this.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be null (not an empty string / default value), but try this...

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["SerialNumber"] == null) {
    // ...
}
```

If you know *SerialNumber* is in the query string, you can use *Request.QueryString*, otherwise you'll be also be checking the form variables, cookies, and server variables.

Comment: Thanks #dbaseman, unfortunately that hasn't worked for me. My code is as follows:
        
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["SerialNumber"] == null)
        {    
  serial = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["SerialNumber"];
            serialNumber.Text = serial;
        }
        else
        {
            serialNumber.Text = "No serial";
        }

Can you see what I've done wrong? I did try to space that out, but you may have to copy it into a document to see it properly, cos it's not spacing properly.

Comment: @Josh it looks like your if/then conditions are backwards, maybe that's the issue.